# Proving that a function is positive

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Let $f(t)$ be a positive function that integrates to $1$. Let $$\phi(t, \sigma) = \frac 1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2\sigma^2}$$

be the pdf of a normal with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
I would like to prove that there always exists $\tilde \sigma > 0$ such that if $\sigma < \tilde \sigma$, then

$$\int_\mathbb R f(t) \phi(t, \sigma) (t^2 - \sigma^2) dt \ge 0$$

This seems like it should be true, but I am struggling to prove it.

**Thoughts**

If we ignore the $f(t)$ in front, we have that

$$\int_\mathbb R \phi(t, \sigma) (t^2 - \sigma^2) dt = 0$$

Now this function is positive for $|t| > \sigma$ and negative otherwise. The negative and positive part of this function perfectly balance each other.

When we multiply by $f(t)$, we are changing this balance (remember $f(t) > 0$). In the worst case, $f(t)$ could be concentrated in a neighbourhood of $0$ so that it "adds" to the negative part of the function more than the positive part. But $f(t)$ does not change with $\sigma$!

So we can find a $\sigma$ such that $f(t)$ contains less than $\epsilon$ area inside it; i.e. we can find $\sigma$ such that

$$\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma} f(t)dt \le \epsilon$$

So intuitively this means that the negative area is "multiplied" by $\epsilon$, while the positive area is "multiplied" by $1-\epsilon$, which means that the integral is overall positive and we are done.

I am not quite sure how to formalize this second part though; any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, this is false :-(

The counterexample is actually rather easy, don't know why I did not think of it before.

Let $f(t) = \frac 12\cdot 1_{[-1, 1]}$ be the pdf of a uniform random variable on $[-1, 1]$.

For any $\sigma < 1$, we see how the negative part of the integral is left untouched, while the positive part is truncated at $1$. Therefore, no matter how small is $\sigma$, the integral will always be negative.